# How to select rows in a dataframe based on values in three columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with more than 1000 rows, and three columns with different values (integers). I would like to select rows, in which the values of three columns are within 2-folds or less of each other.  I have tried this:

```
df = df[(df['B'] >  | < | == 2 * df['D']) & (df['B'] > | < | == 2 * df['F'])]
```

which it did not work!  I am new to Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might want to try:

```
df = df[((df.B>df.D) & (df.B<df.D*2)) & ((df.B>df.F) & (df.B<df.F*2))]
```